# Help needed with random code generator

Tags: c#, random

I am working on a requirement to randomly generate codes(like a random number). The code should be a alphanumeric but should only allow (A-Z0-9]. The user can specify the number of characters in the code. The code can be 4-9 chars long depending on the user input.

an example of the code would be 'AG43', 'XFR4A5UU0'.

Edit :- I am looking at the best way to solve this. I was looking at generating 2 digit random number in the range 11 to 99. If the number is between 65 & 90 (ascii of A-z ), I will use the ascii for it else i will append the number generated to my code string.

Please advise.

Comment: What have you got so far? Where is the problem? Did you try using the Random class?

Comment: How securely random? Do you want to use the crypto random functions or is the Random class OK?

Comment: Is it OK if there are collisions?

Comment: @Rup.........nothing secure. The user wants to assign codes to their business. The length signifies the importance.

Comment: @Brian, we cannot have collisions. But since the codes would be ultimately be saved in DB, we will verify with the db before assigning the new code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var number_of_chars = 4;
var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"; 
var random = new Random(); 
var result = new string( 
    Enumerable.Repeat(chars, number_of_chars) 
              .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]) 
              .ToArray());
```

Comment: be warned... using Random could result is a string of the same character comming out.

Comment: @SwDevMan81.....Thats the answer I am looking for. I love LINQ. There are simple answers to complicated questions.

Comment: Note: This is a self-contained example.  When moving this to real code, you will want `random` to be declared somewhere else as it should only be instantiated once.  Making it a global static (e.g., Jon Skeet's [`Static Random`](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) class) would also be appropriate, but in that case you will need to be careful about threading.

Answer (score 2):

```
public string GetRandomString(int length)
{
    var newBuffer = new byte[length];
    if (length <= 0)
        return null;

    // This was used for a password generator... change this how every needed
    var charSet = ("ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ" +
                   "abcdefghijkmnprstuvxyz" +
                   "23456789").ToCharArray();

    using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
    {
        rng.GetBytes(newBuffer);

        var newChars = newBuffer.Select(b => charSet[b % charSet.Length]).ToArray();
        return new string(newChars);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's easily fixed, but this will bias marginally towards the first 4 characters (you're compressing 256 down to 36 with mod, 256 / 36 = 7 rem 4). D'oh - except you're not, you're not using his 36 characters, you're using 54, similar comment though.

Comment: Over a set of 36 characters each character has about a 2.7% chance of being selected (three of the characters have about a 3.1% chance.)